# Predictive validity question using cubic linear models R

Tags: r, regression, polynomial

I have a data set with 2 months worth of observations from one of our clients, 1 observation per day. I am trying to predict number of sales based on two expenditure methods. My independent variables are Day (as factor), number of online visits, 2 separate expenditure methods.

Both the independent and dependent variables are continuous (apart from Day which is a factor).

Upon fitting numerous model types I have found that 1 of the expenditure methods and online visits had multicolinearity with high VIF. Dropping online visits and using only 2 expenditure methods produced the model that I am using now (I've tried fitting Day into the model but none of the factor levels were significant, my understanding is that I only have 7-8 observations per Day and would need more observations to get a better idea if Day is significant or not)

Current model has quadratic polynomials added to both independent variables to smooth out residuals vs fitted and get a better predicting value.

I've cross validated the model with different fold levels, the model predicts low and high values with quite good accuracy, only a few values are sparsely predicted.

What I've noticed is when I check for summary both my independent variables are now non significant whereas quadratic terms are. Am I correct to think that when adding polynomial terms I can disregard significance levels for the variables that have polynomial terms added to them?

I've used the same model to predict values for the current month since I've only had data for Oct/Nov and the prediction ability of the model is pretty damn good! (so far).

Had a chat with a friend and he advised that perhaps I am over-fitting the model and should try adding a quadratic term only instead of cubic.

Given that predictive power is quite strong with my current model, can I still use the model if independent variables are not significant? (My gut tells me that they should be significant and I did something wrong)

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the spelling in your title (I left "multicolinearity" alone in the body text though).

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about "independent variables" as distinct from "quadratic terms". You should be comparing model fits with and without the quadratic terms. It also sounds as thought you may need to be more specific about implementation details. If you are using quadratic terms that are not orthogonal to the linear ones, the Wald statistics are very likely entirely misleading. In R, for instance you should _not_ be using `I(var^2)` but rather `poly(var, 2)` or `poly(var,3)`

Comment: Aha! I've been using I(var^2). I will change that tomorrow when I have the time. My model without polynomial terms predicts not so well, I have tried logging my response variable but that did not change the prediction value much.

I'll am very eager to try your suggested change tomorrow DWin